# How to get all cell.values except the first row of the sheet

Tags: python, xlrd

**Problem Statement:** So far I can open the .xlsx with xlrd. Now I need to print all the cell.values except the first row, help pls

**Current Code:**

```
{import xlrd


book = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)}
```

**Question:** How can I print all the cell values except from the excel sheet except for the first row?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import xlrd

workbook = open_workbook(os.path.join(filepath + filename),
                         on_demand=True)
yoursheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
allrows = []
for index in range(1, yoursheet.nrows):
    thisrow = yoursheet.row_values(index)
    allrows.append(thisrow)

for rw in allrows: 
    print rw
```

workbook is the .xls file at /filepath/filename ->
worksheet(0) is the first worksheet ->
each row values are stored in the list *allrows* starting with row(1) beccause of the for loop starts at 1 : *for index in range(**1***